# Make Batch File Cmd Window Stay Open For X Seconds

Tags: command-line, batch

I'm running a batch file on a server to dump a MySQL database.

I'd like to have the cmd window stray open for, say, 20 seconds, and then close. That's so if I run it manually I can see that it finished the task .

I tried Sleep 20, but it doesn't look like it works. The file is like this:

```
echo CAMS MySQL database backup

"d:\program files\mysql\mysql server 5.1\bin\mysqldump" -u xxxxxxx -pxxxxxx --result-file="D:\MySQL_Data_Backups\cams\cams.%DATE:~10,4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%.sql" cams

echo Done!
sleep 20
```

When I run this, it closes the window without showing the final echo ("Done!").

If I use pause instead of sleep, it does show the final echo, but I would like the window to close after a delay.

Any suggestions as to what I have done wrong pls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
@echo off
echo done
ping 127.0.0.0 -n 1 -w 20000 > nul
```

-n 1  attempt to connect once
-w 20000 waits 20 sec

@echo off just to have prettier output

Another one is:

```
timeout 20
```

This you can stop even before it counts down to 0.

Comment: "timeout 20" was my choice, nice that I can still close the window during the countdown. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, here's an old-school method using the classic DOS **choice** command.

```
ECHO waiting 5 seconds...
CHOICE /C:AB /D A /T 5 > NUL
```

Comment: I ended up using "timeout 20" as suggested by excrucio, but your suggestion worked just fine too. Cheers.